# Prove the series converges almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Question: Given Lebesgue integrable $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$, prove the following series converges almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$:
$$\varphi(x) = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{t=-k}^k f(t+x)$$

Attempt: Towards a contradiction suppose there is a non-null set $A$ such that for all $x \in A$ we have $\varphi(x)=\infty$.  Somehow I want to conclude that $\int_A f=\infty$ and contradict the integrability of $f$.

Comment: Call $\varphi_k(x)$ the argument of the limit, and see what happens to $\int_0^1 \varphi_k(x)\, dx$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2528249/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I=(-1/2,1/2]$. Then

$$\int_{I}\Big|\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f(x+k)\,dx\Big|\leq \int_{I}\sum_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}|f(x+k)|\,dx=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{I+k}|f(x)|\,dx=\|f\|_1<\infty$$
Here the change of order of summation and integration can be justified by either monotone convegernce, or by Fubini's theorem.

Thus $g(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}f(x+k)<\infty$ a.s for all $x\in I$, which can then be extended as a periodic function.